# Python Networkx MultiDiGraph - change/assign edge keys from pandas dataframe instead of default integer

Tags: python, networkx

I'm building a network using NetworkX using the below code, which works fine.
However, I want to be able to specify (if possible) the edge key which is assigned to each edge (there are multiple edges between some of the nodes). NetworkX defaults to assigning the key to the lowest possible integer but I'd like it to be one of the edge attributes instead. Can this be done during the network setup? or after the fact?

```
Net = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(G, source='K', target='S', edge_attr=['A', 'B', 'C','D'], create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph())
```